# DELETE operation in GET rest service

Tags: web-services, rest

I got a query while developing rest service.

As per the REST design, GET is to read , PUT or POST are to create or update based on scenario , DELETE is to delete the resources.

But technically, Can't we perform a create or delete operation in GET call.
i.e. It is up to client way of calling by using specified URL pattern and required response type to hit the exact method in the service class of REST application. But why can't we perform a delete or create of some data in the GET service.

so my question is the DELETE or CREATE technically not possible in GET service or is it a rule to adhere to REST principles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> so my question is the DELETE or CREATE technically not possible in GET service or is it a rule to adhere to REST principles.

The latter. It is only a convention to use the DELETE HTTP method for delete operations. However using the GET HTTP method for delete operations is a bad idea. Below is a quote from "RESTful Java with JAX-RS 2.0, 2nd Edition" that explains why:

> It is crucial that we do not assign
>   functionality to an HTTP method that supersedes the specification-defined boundaries
>   of that method. For example, an HTTP GET on a particular resource should be readonly.
>   It should not change the state of the resource it is invoking on. Intermediate services
>   like a proxy-cache, a CDN (Akamai), or your browser rely on you to follow the semantics
>   of HTTP strictly so that they can perform built-in tasks like caching effectively. If you
>   do not follow the definition of each HTTP method strictly, clients and administration
>   tools cannot make assumptions about your services, and your system becomes more
>   complex

Answer (score 1):

> so my question is the DELETE or CREATE technically not possible in GET
>   service or is it a rule to adhere to REST principles?

REST uses standards aka. uniform interface constraint. One of these standards is the HTTP standards which defines the HTTP methods. According to the HTTP standard the GET is a safe method:

> In particular, the convention has been established that the GET and
>   HEAD methods SHOULD NOT have the significance of taking an action
>   other than retrieval. These methods ought to be considered "safe".
>   This allows user agents to represent other methods, such as POST, PUT
>   and DELETE, in a special way, so that the user is made aware of the
>   fact that a possibly unsafe action is being requested.

According to the RFC 2119:

> 4. SHOULD NOT - This phrase, or the phrase "NOT RECOMMENDED" mean that    there may exist valid reasons in particular circumstances when the particular behavior is acceptable or even useful, but the full implications should be understood and the case carefully weighed before implementing any behavior described with this label.

For example write can be a side effect by GET, if you want to increase the visitor count by each request.

Answer (score 0):

How the server software (API) is constructed and what 'rules' are applied is somewhat 'arbitrary'. Developers and their product managers could enforce 'rules' such as 'thou shalt not code or support DELETE operations through the GET operation', but in practice, that is not necessarily the main reason POST is chosen over GET.  As others have mentioned, there may be assumptions based on the HTTP protocol that other vendors may rely on, but that is a rather complex and not necessarily relevant reasoning.  For instance, your application may be built to connect directly to a server application, and another vendor's rules may not apply.

In a simpler example, on the world wide web and due to compliance and other factors, query string has a limited byte length. Because of this, operations that require a lot of data, such as a few very long encrypted data strings that might be needed for a DELETE operation in a database, GET may not be able to pass enough data, so POST may be the only viable option.

Custom built applications using a CuRL library might extend to include other RESTful operations with their intended functionality, but that would be for the benefit of the server API. Coding more operations on the client-side doesn't necessarily make things 'easier', 'faster', or necessarily 'more secure' from the client perspective, but doing so could help manage resources (a bit) on the server side and help maintain compatibility with third party software and appliances.